# Extract the data from QR Codes and create a new QR code with colour

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

Has anyone heard of this before ? Extract the [`QR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) `Codes` (all the QR Codes must be in same Width and Height {square}) and get the data from each `QR Code`, and combine them. Then get the every pixel value from each QR Code and change them to `hexadecimal`.
You will give `#FFFFFFFF`, `#FF000000`, `#00000000` (white,black, transparent) and the like (but for black and white `QR Code`, it would only 2 of them). Then for each value from each `QR` Code, by creating a **new colour** `QR Code` which the colour is according to the value from each hexadecimal and the content of the new colour `QR Code` will have the content that was extracted from the previous `QR Codes`.

For example, what I am doing now is extract 8 numbers of `QR Code` and combine the content, then create a new `colour QR Code`.

By now, I am stuck in the middle of the process. I have successfully extracted the content and the pixel of each `QR Code` by changing the value to `hexadecimal`. the problem is how can I can change the `hexadecimal` value from each `QR code` to `ARGB` (alpha, Red, Green, Blue) colour and create a new colour `QR Code`.

However, I have tip from Google, some say [`MatrixToImageWriter`](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/javase/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/j2se/MatrixToImageWriter.java) would be useful. But there is not really much work there that is similar and useful to me. Well, I need some help here. However, I am not sure whether it will be useful for me or not.

### PS: I can attach my work here if someone want to.

### PSS: I am using the `Zxing` library to scan and get the result from each `QR Code`.

Comment: +1, looking forward for the issue since i am interested on your question which seems like is combining the QR Code and get the larger QR code to store more data.

Comment: @Kopi Bryant ***"PS: I can attach my work here if someone want to"*** Yes, that would be helpful, (probably).

Comment: Give @Martin Zeitler his QR examples ;O)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just wrote the desired decode/encode methods; the matrix look different because I've created the input QR code with the [QR Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr) application and the output QR code with [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), which might use a different level of error correction; nevertheless both have the same destination URL, which is mine.

The dependencies originate from repositories `google()` and `mavenCentral()`:

```
dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing
    implementation "com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3"
    implementation "com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0"
}
```

The layout resource used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/inputImage"
        android:src="@drawable/qrcode"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/outputImage"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

And the manipulation of the `BitMatrix`; where the `encode()` method should suffice, when having the `String` available; just added both methods for the sake of a complete example (it reads the `Bitmap` from one `AppCompatImageView` and then writes to another one `AppCompatImageView`):

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.ColorInt;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
import com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.NotFoundException;
import com.google.zxing.RGBLuminanceSource;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.common.HybridBinarizer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppCompatImageView mInputImage;
    private AppCompatImageView mOutputImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        this.mInputImage = this.findViewById(R.id.inputImage);
        this.mOutputImage = this.findViewById(R.id.outputImage);

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) this.mInputImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        String data = this.decode(bitmap);

        bitmap = this.encode(data, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 0xFFFFD034,0xFF06425C);
        this.mOutputImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private String decode(Bitmap bitmap) {

        String data = null;
        MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
        int[] intArray = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
        bitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), intArray);
        BinaryBitmap binary = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

        try {
            Result result = reader.decode(binary);
            data = result.getText();
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("ZXing", "decoded: " + data);
        return data;
    }

    private Bitmap encode(String contents, int width, int height, @ColorInt int foreground, @ColorInt int background) {

        MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
        BitMatrix matrix = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            matrix = writer.encode(contents, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(matrix != null) {
            int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int offset = y * width;
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    pixels[offset + x] = matrix.get(x, y) ? foreground : background;
                }
            }
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

The result looks alike this; where the left one is the input matrix and the right one is the output matrix:

[image: QR Codes, Input & Output Matrix]

Comment: well, this is helpful. what if i want to set the pixel (e.g pixel[1][10] to blue color, pixel[20][20] to red color, some sort like this) of the qr code in the color i want ?

Comment: @KopiBryant you could add a method, which obtains a substitute color code for one of the colors (eg. by reading from a photo, by the current x/y coordinate). be aware, that the colors should start with `0xFF` (zero transparency); also, color combinations which provide a low contrast might prevent the proper detection. [complimentary colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_colors) should work well... and one can do an awful lot with QR (...), but the error correction still has it's limits.

Comment: see [EncodeHintType](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/EncodeHintType.html) for further settings one can pass into the [MultiFormatWriter](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/MultiFormatWriter.html) (after argument `height`), which permits adjusting eg. the level of error correction - or the QR version, which to output.

Comment: well, it would be helpful and appreciated if there is some example code.

Comment: @KopiBryant wasn't part of the question, which I've already answered and even provided further clues... besides it is not even clear what the purpose is, of what you're trying to do. see [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)... and programming is my bread (as the example QR code might hint for), so I can't just go above and beyond of what was asked. asking a new question with a bounty might be your best chance to get such an example.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after few days of digging from the Internet. I have found the solution and I think it would help someone else someday.

```
 QRCodeWriter qw = new QRCodeWriter();

try {
    HashMap<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new HashMap<>();
    hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8");
    hints.put(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, margin);
    BitMatrix matrix = qw.encode(msg, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, hints);
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
            bmp.setPixel(x, y, matrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return bmp;
} catch (WriterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To change the color of the QR Code and if you have an `arraylist` like mine that store all the `hex` String. You can using `for` loops and to insert the `hex` String.

For changing the color, based on the code,

```
 for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
        bmp.setPixel(x, y, matrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

The Color.Black can be replace with the `arraylist` (in my case, I replace it with my `colorArray`) and Color.White is the color for the background of a QR Code.

Well, hope it helps someone somedays. *Happy coding*.